# I want to include My theme file (testing.php) to inside my plugin folder (myplugin/mypugin.php)

Tags: plugins, theme-development

Any One can suggest me..

I have a theme file testing.php(this is a theme file). I want to include this file to myplugin folder file.

Comment: For what purpose? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: First Milan thanks for comment ):-

I have install a plugin yth-multistep-checkout plugin..these plugin file takes all code from woo commerce plugin core files using hooks. So i want to not change anything in woo commerce plugin core file..

I want  to take code from my theme folder woo commerce files. So we want include these file code to yth-multicheckout-plugin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hooks is what plugin is supposed to do. Using hooks ensures that core files are not changed. Woo theme files from the theme are based on the core Woo files from WooCommerce plugin, so they share same hooks. And that is the way it should work.

Also, you can't include files from theme into a random plugin, it doesn't work that way. And since that YTH plugin already uses hooks, that is all OK, and no core files will be changed. All WooCommerce plugins work that way.